# Suppress function output with markdown

Tags: r, function, output, markdown, suppress

I'm trying to create a markdown document from R. Below is my code. It works perfect, however I source a function (tryFun() from tryFun.R). The output of this function I store in a variable. When I do this, it automatically also prints the output. However, I want to determine myself where I use the output of that variable, so later on, I call it. How can I suppress the output of the function when I assign the results to a variable?

Code in tryRmd.R :

````
#' ---
#' title: "Try for the first time"
#' output: word_document
#' params: 
#'    xvar: "" 
#' ---

#' ## Introduction 
#' Hi, this is me trying something for the first time 
#' #Hello again 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(1:100)
#x <- 3
source("tryFun.r")
cat("hi")
xvar <- params$xvar 
x1 <- invisible(tryFun(xvar)) 
### shows a plot here (want to suppress this)
cat(x1$res)
plot.new()
x1$p 
### shows the same plot here
```
````

and the code in tryFun.R is:

```
tryFun <- function(x){
    res = 3*x
    plot(1:1000)
    p <- recordPlot()
    return(list(res=res,p=p))
}
```

and my output is of the form:

Title

Text

Plot (1:100)

Plot (1:1000) from calling `x1 <- invisible(tryFun(xvar))` (This is what I don't want to show)

9 (from calling `cat(x1$res))`

Plot (1:1000) from calling `x1$p`

I render the document in this way:

```
library(rmarkdown)

dire = "D:/"
filename = paste(dire, "tryRmd.r", sep="/")

rmarkdown::render(filename, params=list(xvar=3))
```

**Update**

I changed the code to this:

````
#' ---
#' title: "Try for the first time"
#' output: word_document
#' params: 
#'    xvar: "" 
#' ---

#' ## Introduction 
#' Hi, this is me trying something for the first time 
#' #Hello again 
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='hide'}
plot(1:100)
direct = "G:/Documents/WarehouseMovements"
filename <- paste(direct, "pickingsregels_wmp700_monthly_201711.txt", sep="/")
#x <- 3
source("tryFun.r")

xvar <- params$xvar 
x1 <- invisible(tryFun(xvar)) 
### shows a plot here (wants to suppress this)
``` 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
cat("hi")
cat(x1$res)
plot.new()
x1$p 
### shows the same plot here
```
````

But it still shows the plot when calling `x1 <- invisible(tryFun(xvar))`.

Comment: Have a look at `results = 'hide'` in the chunks setting.

Comment: When I change ` ```{r, echo = FALSE}` into  ` ```{r, echo = FALSE, results='hide'}`, I still get all three plots, but the 9 (x1$res) is gone.. As also the text "hi"

Comment: Of course, that was because it was in the same chunk. Changed that, but still does not suppress the plot with results='hide'

Answer (score 0):

I found it. While results='hide' did do nothing, include=FALSE did.

So my code looks like this:

````
#' ---
#' title: "Try for the first time"
#' output: word_document
#' params: 
#'    xvar: "" 
#' ---

#' ## Introduction 
#' Hi, this is me trying something for the first time 
#' #Hello again 
```{r, echo=FALSE,include=FALSE}
plot(1:100)
direct = "G:/Documents/WarehouseMovements"
filename <- paste(direct, "pickingsregels_wmp700_monthly_201711.txt", sep="/")
#x <- 3
source("tryFun.r")

xvar <- params$xvar 
x1 <- invisible(tryFun(xvar)) 
### shows a plot here (wants to suppress this)
``` 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
cat("hi")
cat(x1$res)
plot.new()
x1$p 
### shows the same plot here
```
````